# How to close PyQt app cleanly

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, signals-slots

I have developed an application which will have a PyQt trayIcon with context menus. When its run it is placed in the system tray. This app will not have exit button except for selected designations in the organization.

This app is configured and placed at system startup, so when every an employee login to his/her system it will track his login and update the employee availability to 'Online'  in the database.

Till this point everything is working fine. The main issue is when he/she LogOff or Shutdown the system and leave office. At this point i need to update employee availability to 'Offline' in the database. I dont know how to track these system events.

I tried below signals

1. lastWindowClosed()
2. aboutToQuit()
3. destroyed()
4. overloading closeEvent()

My close definition never execute at any of these signals when i initiate Logoff/Shutdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [QSessionManager](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsessionmanager.html) class that is designed for this task, although it seems it may work better on some platforms than others. See [Session Management overview](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/session.html) for more details.

Comment: thx for your suggestion, as its an alternate, i can accept as answer for my question +1